# list of figures is empty?

Tags: floats, lists

hello i wanted to hide sections and subsections from the list of contents  but to  keep them in the body so i used  the code below :

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\listoffigures
```

and  it worked but then the list of figures that was full is empty now and shows nothing,so how can i hide the sections and subsections without effecting the list of figures?

Comment: why `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} ` rather than simply `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` ?

Comment: because i already used like u said but it didn't work

Comment: The list of figures mostly uses section level to represent figures. So you might want to restore at least section level before using the command.

Comment: something not working isn't exactly a reason for using something else that's very weird and also doesn't work:-) I see Heiko has posted some working version.

Answer (score 2):

Figures and tables have the toc level 1, from `report.cls`:

```
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

`\l@<type>` is the internal command for setting an entry in the table of contents and lists for object `<type>` (`chapter`, `section`, `figure`, ...).
The first argument of `\@dottedtocline` contains the level. It is suppressed, if the level is larger than `tocdepth`, from `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % = \value{tocdepth}
    % Entry is suppressed
  \else
    % ...
  \fi
}
```

Setting the value of `tocdepth` to one for the list of figures should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```